# Suddenly gcloud not working at all, it says something is corrupted

Tags: spring-cloud, gcloud

All gcloud command gives this error
ERROR: gcloud gailed to load: File contains no section headers.

googlecloudsdk.core.configurations.properties_file.PropertirsParseError: File contains no section headers.

Answer (score 0):

You've corruption in your `gcloud` installation.

It's possible this is limited to your local configuration. If so, and you don't mind deleting the configuration, assuming you're on Linux, **please backup** before deleting `${HOME}/.config/gcloud`.

Then try e.g. `gcloud init` .

**If that doesn't work**, and if you're able to do so, I then recommend uninstalling and then reinstalling Cloud SDK (aka `gcloud`) on your machine.

See: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

> Interestingly there's also a typo in the error message `Propertirs`